# How to access the FOTT @ Azurewebsites for GA 2.1?

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I see that there is a new GA release of FOTT. We have custom training that needs to be updated, however I can't seem to find the correct URL to use FOTT at Azuresites to do custom training. I don't see anything in the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/whats-new?tabs=csharp

I have been using the preview version (https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/) to this point and have been waiting for this update. When I go to what I thought was the GA release (https://fott.azurewebsites.net/) it appears to be the older version from prior to the preview releases.

The readme at github states that GA release is 2.0, not 2.1, and makes no mention of a GA release of 2.1.
https://github.com/microsoft/OCR-Form-Tools/tree/master

Switching to the "v2.1-General-Availability-Release" doesn't help me find the answer either.

Thank you,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

To get started and use the 2.1 API GA release please use 2.1 GA FOTT -
https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/

Thanks for the feedback fixing our documentation also.

-Neta MSFT